# How to create reusable functions in Vuejs?

Tags: function, vue.js, methods, reusability

I have this function in a Vuejs File which calls another function which is imported from a JS File.

Demo.vue

```
import Data from "demofile.js"

created(){
  this.getResult()
}

methods(){
async getResult(){
      Data.example() // Fetching Data from API
      .then((results) =>{
        this.$set(this,"results",results) // storing in event data()
        console.log(this.results)
    })
    .catch(e =>console.log(e, "Error from catch"))
  }
 }
```

I want to make this function reusable so that I could use it on any other VueJS files.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution which I like more.

Create inside `src/` a folder with name `utils` and inside the folder create .js file like `globalFunctions.js` and add the method

```
export const consoleLogName = (input) => {
    console.log(input)
  }
```

And then in Component.vue import the file:

```
import { consoleLogName} from "@/utils/globalFunctions";
```

and register the method in methods like:

```
methods:{
 consoleLogName: consoleLogName,
 otherMethodhere(){
  ......
 }
}
```

or with desctructuring providing the same name, this is a shortcut:

```
 methods:{
     consoleLogName,
     otherMethodhere(){
      ......
     }
 }
```

and use it in template as a regular method:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <span @click="consoleLogName('My Name')"></span>
 </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixins to re-use your functions in other Vue.js files.

Official documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html